# OBIEE12c(12.2.1.4) configuration assistant failed at create domain step

Tags: oracle, obiee

Stack Trace:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Action:BI_Configuration failed with error:Configure BI Failed with Execution of [/app/middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh, /app/middleware/Oracle_Home/bi/modules/oracle.bi.configassistant/create_base_domain.py, /app/middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/bi, weblogic, true, 9500, 9501, 9506, obieehost] failed with exit value 134
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.client.ConfigAction.fail(ConfigAction.java:281)
at oracle.bi.install.config.actions.BIConfigAction.doExecute(BIConfigAction.java:137)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.client.ConfigAction.execute(ConfigAction.java:405)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.TaskPerformer.run(TaskPerformer.java:88)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.TaskPerformer.startConfigAction(TaskPerformer.java:108)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.ActionRequest.perform(ActionRequest.java:15)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.RequestQueue.performSequentialExecution(RequestQueue.java:284)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.RequestQueue.perform(RequestQueue.java:260)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.standard.StandardConfigActionManager.start(StandardConfigActionManager.java:185)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.boot.ConfigurationExtension.kickstart(ConfigurationExtension.java:82)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.ConfigurationModule.run(ConfigurationModule.java:87)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
In Config Module Finish Event...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix the issue, need to make changes in the following two files.

1. open the file $ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin/setWlstEnv_internal.sh/setWlstEnv_internal.cmd in a text editor

change the line

JVM_ARGS="${WLST_PROPERTIES} ${JVM_D64} ${UTILS_MEM_ARGS} ${CONFIG_JVM_ARGS}"

To

JVM_ARGS="-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/../dev/urandom ${WLST_PROPERTIES} ${JVM_D64} ${UTILS_MEM_ARGS} ${CONFIG_JVM_ARGS}"

2. Open the $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security file in a text editor.

   Change the line:

   securerandom.source=file:/dev/random

   To

   securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Oracle support then this seems to be documented https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Enterprise%20Performance%20Management%20and%20Business%20Intelligence/2388947_1.html